# What is it called when a class property is an instance of another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Very basic question here, look at my property **Order** in my **customer class**. Wondering what is the formal name of a property type like this is (yes, this could also be a list).

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Order Orders { get; set; }  // what am i called?
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Its called an object of another class.

Comment: You may see that referred to as a "complex" property, since simple serialization of the `Customer` object will result in some nested XML or JSON for that property. But I don't think that's an "official" term.

Comment: Why did you pluralize that property name? It's not a collection.

Comment: There's no special name for it these days - it's just another property. And notice how I changed your title. That's the correct terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the same thing. Its called a "Property". There is no different name for it. Consider your `SomeProperty` which is of type `string`. `string` is also a class and `SomeProperty` is its object. Same convention with your class would follow as well.

From [C# Language Specification.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx)

> **1.6.7.2 Properties**
>
> A property is declared like a field, except that the declaration ends
>   with a get accessor and/or a set accessor written between the
>   delimiters { and } instead of ending in a semicolon.

So the term "property" in C# is associated with the accessors *(get/set)*

Answer (score 2):

from [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) 8.7.4:

> A property is a member that provides access to a characteristic of an object or a class.

It doesn't matter what type the property accesses.  The *property* itself is just to provide access to it.

So, bottom line, a property is a property no matter what type it accesses.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a property - there's not a formal name for it.

Answer (score 1):

The concept itself is called Composition.  Basically, you want to be able to use a Customer object to get information about an Order, but you don't want the logic that gets that information to live in Customer. So, you have a member who is an Order and Order encapsulates the Order behavior.

You could say that a Customer is composed of Order along with other values.

Have a link: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html

Not that you asked this, but you probably will want an actual collection of Orders.  You could start with
`public List<Order> Orders;`

Answer (score 0):

It's still a property. It just gets/sets an object, which is an instance of a class.